Glasser Master Theorem Usage Outside the function
i found an integral solution to the p47 question in this thread in AOPS  1: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1288609_extreme_integration_marathon
I know how the glasser theorem works but how does he manipulate outside the function sech the $x^2$ term i still find it new can someone explain it here to me thanks
The Problem:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \operatorname{sech}\frac{x^4-10x^2+6x+7}{x^3-7x+6}\mathrm{d}x$$
Answer from AOPS:


If you mean this calculation, please edit it into your question, preferably as MathJax.

It's a bit more general than GMT, but with the usual motivation. It's writing$$x^2\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}\tfrac13x^3=\mathrm{d}g(y)=g'(y)\mathrm{d}y$$where $g(y)$ is the sum of $\tfrac13x^3$ over all $x$ that obtain a given $y$. By the way, do you know how to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty(y^2+3)\operatorname{sech}y\mathrm{d}y$?

Okay now i already get some of the motivation , now for the over all x is it the root of it
